# What's the most effective way to match out data from <table > with PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex

For example,to strip out key/value pairs from html like below:

```
<tr> 
          <td id="td3"  class="td3"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="4">■ Related Information </td>

        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="10%">job title：</td>
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="90%" colspan="3">Sales Representitive</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="10%">Date：</td>

          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="40%">2009-9-15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="10%">Location：</td>

          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="40%">Jiangyin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="10%">Degree:</td>
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="40%">Bachelor</td>

          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="10%">Major：</td>
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="40%">No limit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="10%">Sex：</td>
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="40%">No limit</
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="10%">Type：</td>
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="40%">Fulltime</td>
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="10%"></td>
          <td id="td5" class="td5" width="40%"></td>
        </tr>
```

I've been tired of writing long regular expression.
Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Simple PHP usually generates html, not parses it. Are you telling us the whole story? Are you using PHP at the command line?

Comment: @pavium,yes,at the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Use an HTML or XML parser like [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/domdocument) or [SimpleXML](http://docs.php.net/simplexml). Then you can simply traverse the DOM and fetch the data you want.

Comment: Can both of them be used to parse HTML?

Comment: @Shore: SimpleXML can only parse XML. But DOMDocument can parse both HTML and XML.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some simple regular expressions:

```
$values = array();
if (preg_match_all("/<tr>(.*?)<\/tr>/is", $html, $matches)) {
 foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
  if (preg_match_all("/<td[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/td>/is", $match, $tds))
   array_push($values, $tds[1]);
 }
}

var_dump($values);
```

It is a lot simpler when separate the patterns instead of one single large pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the lesser known [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It lets you do stuff like this:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

---

```
// Create DOM from string
$html = str_get_html('<div id="hello">Hello</div><div id="world">World</div>');

$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'bar';

$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';

echo $html; // Output: <div id="hello">foo</div><div id="world" class="bar">World</div>
```